# Getting multiple hash query string values in an array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The purpose of this code is to open two different tabs where one tab is nested inside main tab. When user click a link which passes a query string hash values like the following

`http://127.0.0.1:5500/products/virtual-machines.html#Get_Started#v-pills-02-tab`

I need to open both tabs at once when page loads.Bootstrap 5 is the plugin used for. I tried using the following code.

```
var hash = location.hash.split('?')[0];
    console.log(hash);
    if (hash) {
        var triggerEl = document.querySelector("#" + hash + '');
        triggerEl.click();
    }
```

result

```
#Get_Started#v-pills-02-tab
```

I need to slipt in two var

```
Get_Started

v-pills-02-tab
```

Comment: You literally are using a function called `.split()` in *in your own code*. Please, if you copy code off of the Internet then don't just paste it and go on hunting for the next bit of code you can copy. At least read the code you have copied, and understand what it does. I don't get how this question even came to be, other than that you're already running code you did not write yourself, and did not even bother reading.

Comment: I am a designer and a beginner in javascript/jQuery. If my question doesnt rise upto your point of expertise, please disregard.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is splitting on a question mark (?), which doesn't exist in your hash.

Perhaps you could write your hash as a comma separated list, the first item in the list would be the parent tab element id, and the 2nd item would be the child tab element id, etc.

```
http://127.0.0.1:5500/products/virtual-machines.html#Get_Started,v-pills-02-tab
```

Then parse it, splitting on the comma.

```
// substring out the leading '#' 
//   and convert the comma-separated items into an array
var tabIds = location.hash.substring(1).split(',');
if(tabIds) {
  var $tab = $('#' + tabIds[0]);

  // Ensure that the element exists before clicking it
  if($tab.length > 0) {
    $tab.click();

    // Check for subsequent tab-ids
    if(tabIds.length > 1) {
      var $subTab = $('#' + tabIds[1]);
      if($subTab.length > 0) {
        $subTab.click();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(Sorry if you're allergic to jQuery.  It shouldn't be difficult to translate it to vanilla JS.)